# SQL - generate a list of cheapest options

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

The schema is a little bit strange. I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [VenueId] [int] NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Venues](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AveragePrice] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

And data like this:

```
insert into Venues (Id, Name, AveragePrice) VALUES
  (1, 'Arena1', 100),
  (1, 'Arena2', 200),
  (1, 'Arena3', 50),
  (2, 'Club1', 50),
  (2, 'Club2', 150)

 insert into Events (Id, Name, VenueId) VALUES
   (1, 'ConsertAtArena1', 1),
   (2, 'ConsertAtArena2', 1),
   (3, 'ConsertAtArena3', 1),
   (2, 'Conference', NULL)
```

I need to produce: `'ConsertAtArena3', 'Conference'`. That is the cheapest Venue option for events with the same VenueId plus all events with NULL VenueId. The tables are quite massive, up to a few million rows. What would be an efficient SELECT to do it?

The database is SQL Server 2012 Standard.

Comment: Add the expected result as well.

Comment: All you need is Execution Plan to see query cost !

Comment: How is `'ConsertAtArena3'` the *cheapest*?  All three concerts have the same `venueId` reference, so they would all have the same prices.

Comment: There are multiple venues with the same `VenueId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem in the way you store your data. In your example all `'ConcertAtArena1'`, `'ConcertAtArena2'` and `'ConcertAtArena3'` are linked to the same venue that you defined multiple times in the `Venues` table.

Why isn't the correct answer '`ConcertAtArena1'` as an event for `'Arena3'` since the id of the venue is the same. Are you using some kind of fussy logic on the name there?

I suspect you should either store the Arenas as different venues or add another sub-table where you have the price and each arena is unique. Here's an example where I added an extra table called Arenas:

```
DECLARE @Events TABLE (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ArenaId] [int] NULL
) 

DECLARE @Venues TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) 

DECLARE @arenas TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VenueId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AveragePrice] [int] NOT NULL
) 


insert into @venues (id, name) values 
(1, 'Venue1'),
(2, 'Venue2')

insert into @arenas (Id, VenueId, Name, AveragePrice) VALUES
  (1,1, 'Arena1', 100),
  (2,1, 'Arena2', 200),
  (3,1, 'Arena3', 50),
  (4,2, 'Club1', 50),
  (5,2, 'Club2', 150)

 insert into @Events (Id, Name, ArenaId) VALUES
   (1, 'ConsertAtArena1', 1),
   (2, 'ConsertAtArena2', 2),
   (3, 'ConsertAtArena3', 3),
   (4, 'Conference', NULL)

;WITH ranked AS (
SELECT e.Id, a.AveragePrice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.VenueId ORDER BY a.AveragePrice) AS rn 
FROM @Events e
LEFT OUTER JOIN @arenas a ON a.Id = e.ArenaId)

SELECT e.id,e.name,r.AveragePrice FROM @Events e
INNER JOIN ranked r ON r.Id = e.Id
WHERE r.rn = 1
```

With this query you'l get `'ConcertAtArena3'` with average price 50 and `'Conference'` with average price NULL

Comment: I don't have control over the schema, it's what it is.

Comment: I get that but, as I explained in the first part of my answer, you don't have the consistency in your data to retrieve that information.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ionut, I appreciate it. I see what you mean and I'll have to think about it.